# Exibir os valores do acelerometro android em graus

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android que utiliza o sensor ACELEROMETRO. Preciso medir a inclinação em graus. Consegui instanciar o sensor obter as medidas do mesmo, exibir os eixos X, Y e Z em TextViews. Porém, os valores que o sensor me retorna não são em graus. Pesquisei para ver se encontrava em que unidade esses dados são exibidos/medidos pelo ACELEROMETRO, mas sem sucesso.
Desde já agradeço a quem puder me ajudar.

```
//Atributos para trabalhar com a camera
private Camera camera;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;
private ShowCamera showCamera;

//Atributos para trabalhar com os eixos
private TextView textViewX;
private TextView textViewY;
private TextView textViewZ;

//Atributos para trabalhar com o Acelerometro
private Sensor sensor;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutCamera);

    this.camera = Camera.open();
    this.showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, camera);
    this.frameLayout.addView(showCamera);

    textViewX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewX);
    textViewY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewY);
    textViewZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewZ);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    textViewX.setText("" + event.values[0]);
    textViewY.setText("" + event.values[1]);
    textViewZ.setText("" + event.values[2]);

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

Comment: Suponho que esteja a usar o sensor errado.

Comment: Qual seria o sensor indicado para medir inclinação em graus?

Comment: Tem de usar dois, veja a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-orient)